# how to pack a std::string as a std::tuple<Ts...>

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, stdstring, stdtuple

I have a parameter pack like

```
<int, long, string, double>
```

and a string like

```
"100 1000 hello 1.0001"
```

how can I resolve these data and pack them into a std::tuple<int, long, string, double>

Comment: You first need to split the string into a vector of 4 strings, one for each value. You can use functions such as `std::string::find` and `std::string:::substr`. Then you can convert each value to as needed. For string to int, use `std::stoi`. For string to double, use `std::stod`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to use `std::apply` to expand the elements of the `tuple` and use `istringstream` to extract the formatted data and assign it to the element

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  std::string s = "100 1000 hello 1.0001";
  std::tuple<int, long, std::string, double> t;
  auto os = std::istringstream{s};
  std::apply([&os](auto&... x) {
    (os >> ... >> x);
  }, t);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W14hq5Pqb)